# Table of contents/Index inside R file

Tags: r, rstudio

I have a very long R script files (one has 2723 lines), can I create a Table of Contents or Index to navigate through a file?

I would like to create a table of contents that points to a specific line on my text, say I have 20 variables to analyze, a table of contents would have 20 items.

Comment: What exactly do you want the table of contents or index to contain. What do you want them to point to?

Comment: that exists in r studio. in standalone R? maybe `control/command + f`?

Comment: I break my code into logical blocks (as best I can), then `source` these files with `source("file1.R", echo=TRUE)`. This is kind of like a table of contents, but it's not costless.

Comment: if this exists in Rstudio where is it?

Comment: see @zx8754's answer. Then a list of the chunks (with names) appears at the bottom of your editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can insert sections using `CTRL`+`SHIFT`+`R` (`Cmd`+`Shift`+`R` on the Mac)

For more detail, see [Code Folding and Sections](https://www.rstudio.com/ide/docs/using/code_folding)

> **Code Folding** RStudio supports both automatic and user-defined folding for regions of code. Code folding allows you to easily show
>   and hide blocks of code to make it easier to navigate your source file
>   and focus on the coding task at hand.
>
> ...
>
> To navigate between code sections you can use the Jump To menu
>   available at the bottom of the editor:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I understand now the "table of contents" displays at the bottom. thank you very much.

Comment: @user3083324 added image to clarify.

Comment: Can I compile a section?

Comment: Please avoid posting new question here. As @RichardHerron suggested above, it is better to separate code into smaller chunk of codes, and use `source()`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can click the button on the right top corner, Next to the source button.
Unfortunately, I can't post the pic here.

Or if you want to export to PDF, HTML, or even a word file of your codes with its results, you can try Rmarkdown to make a TOC instead of a script.